# Laravel: custom multidimensional array validation

Tags: php, validation, multidimensional-array, laravel, laravel-4

I've a form which user will insert many records at a time. Each record will have an *id*, a *start date* and an *end date*. To process the input data, I'm looking for the *best* way to validate all these things.

- I'll have to require at least one record
- For each inputed record, *id* should exists at another table, *date start* and *end date* should be valid dates and *end date* should be older than *start date*

So I need some sort of multidimensional array validation here... Is there any custom validation plugin/code already coded for that?

I've tried to extend Laravel validation but I couldn't get even close to what I'd like...

What I've tried:

*app/services/validators/LearningPathValidator.php* (I'm using *laravel-extended-validator*)

```
<?php

use Crhayes\Validation\ContextualValidator;

class LearningPathValidator extends ContextualValidator
{
    protected $rules = [
        'default' => [
            'name'    => 'required|max:96',
            'courses' => 'required|multi_array:course_id=required;exists:courses,date_start=required;date_format:d/m/Y,date_end=required;date_format:d/m/Y'
        ],
    ];
}
```

*app/validations.php* (Here I'm extending *Illuminate\Validation\Validator* class)

```
<?php

class AppValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator
{
    protected function validateMultiArray($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            return false;
        }

        foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
            list($_attribute, $rules) = $this->parseRule(
                str_replace(['=', ';'], [':', ','], $parameter));

            foreach ($rules as $rule) {
                foreach (array_keys(Input::get($attribute)) as $idx){
                    $this->validate(sprintf('%s.%d.%s', $attribute, $idx,
                        snake_case($_attribute)), $rule);
                }
            }
        }

        return count($this->messages->all()) === 0;
    }
}
```

My *start/global.php*: (Here I extend *Illuminate\Validation\Validator* with *AppValidator*)

```
// ...

Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
    return new AppValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});

// ...
```

My models are using `courses[$index][course_id]`, `courses[$index][date_start]` and `courses[$index][date_end]` as field names.

Actually I can't require at least one record as I said before and I can't assure *end date* will be older than *start date*. Any suggestions to rewrite what I've coded? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Here's an something from the forums which claims to work http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=31171

Comment: Hsve you considered using AJAX in order to have only one request at the time?

Answer (score 1):

I created a package to do just this as I encountered the same problem with data from AngularJS.

https://github.com/lakedawson/vocal